# Laravel11 mysql migration problem with collation: "General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'"

Tags: laravel, mariadb

After installing fresh laravel 11 and changing database driver to mysql in .env I can't run `php artisan migrate`, error:

```
 General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update after laravel 11.0.3

Workaround is not needed, they reverted it right now
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/6372

#### Before laravel 11.0.3

after [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/6367) and [this discussion](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/79969c99c6456a6d6edfbe78d241575fe1f65594)

Now they fixed config so just use MariaDB connection:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mariadb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

#### After laravel 11 update:

Laravel **changed default** DB_COLLATION from utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

When we are using mariadb (for example xampp in windows) there is no this kind of collation. According to this [table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/supported-character-sets-and-collations/).

We have to use other collation. In your .env add:

```
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

so finally working .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

then `php artisan migrate` works.