Laravel migration error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
I did everything found in internet, nothing helps.
I have a problem with Laravel migration. My OS is Windows 11. XAMPP. I use WSL.
I am entering

php artisan migrate

Settings are:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Output:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'intsys' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

Then I am changing

DB_HOST=localhost

Output:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'intsys' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)


DB_HOST=mysql

also doesn't work.
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'intsys' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

I added

DB_SOCKET=/mnt/c/xampp1/mysql/mysql.sock

and result is:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'intsys' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

path to socket in settings is

socket="C:/xampp1/mysql/mysql.sock"

The port is definitely 3306 and mysql is working now.
Also I have a line

extension=pdo_mysql.so

in php.ini. And line

extension=pdo_mysql

too.
What is the solution?

Did you configure both .env & config/database.php with right credentials?

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

I checked, it is right

what is in config/database.php?

Connection refused usually indicates that MY SQL is not running on your machine.

@IrinaB Change DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 to DB_HOST=localhost to the both file.And run php artisan config:clear then check

Also SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

@IrinaB,this is MySQL connection issue.Which version of laravel you are using?

last Laravel. Mysql is green, it works

"laravel/framework": "^11.9",

Does your problem solve as you said it works?

No, mysql works...

laravel doesn't work

@IrinaB, This might answer your question. Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154387/laravel11-mysql-migration-problem-with-collation-general-error-1273-unknown-c

Connection refused means that either mysql is not running, or runs on a different port, or something else actively blocks the connection. File not found means that the path to the socket file is not correct or your app can't access the file. Both of these questions are being raised on a daily basis, we can't really say or write anything new about them.

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or director again
